# How to plot multiple figures using a loop, then terminate matplotlib.pyplot.show() programmatically?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting multiple figures (in separate windows) using the Python code below.
This opens and plots figures as expected, but after each figure, the script halts, waiting for each window to be closed before the next figure is plotted.  I would like all figures/windows to be plotted sequentially, then the script terminate normally while leaving the figures/windows open.

```
def plot_figure(data: Tuple) -> None:
    """plot ticker in a separate figure from a dataframe
    Args:
        data (tuple): (ticker, dataframe)
    """
    style.use('ggplot')
    df = data[1]
    df.plot.line(x='Date', y=['Open','Close'], figsize=(6,6))
    plt.ylabel('Price $US')
    plt.grid(color='black', linestyle='--', linewidth=1)
    plt.title(data[0].upper(), fontsize=15)
    x = plt.gca().xaxis
    for item in x.get_ticklabels():
        item.set_rotation(90)
    plt.show()

data = [('ticker1', df1), ('ticker2', df2), ('ticker3', df3)]
for figure in data:
   plot_figure(figure)
```

It seems there is an event manager or process invoked by plt.show() that must be terminated before the loop can iterate.
Any recommendations or solutions much appreciated.

Comment: do you want to plot all graphs in one plot ? Or do you want to get multiple pop ups ?

Comment: I want to get multiple pop ups, not all in one plot.